# Orchard default path for CSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Is there a way to point the default CSS path to a different directory in Orchard? I would like to locate my CSS in the content directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard uses the ~/Scripts folder to locate a stylesheet file in a given module or theme, if you provide a relative path. You can change that behavior, but that'd be a hard thing to do and would possibly introduce many errors.

I guess the best way to do would be to provide full path relative to the root, eg:

```
@{ Style.Include("~/Themes/MyThemeName/MyCustomFolder/Site.css"); }
```

If you provide a full path, Orchard will not look for your stylesheet in /Styles folder. Knowing that, you can create an extension method for ResourceRegister, providing your own implementation of Include method, that would append the custom path to the provided one.

Eg:

```
public static ResourceExtensions
{
    public static RequireSettings CustomInclude(this ResourceRegister register, string path)
    {
            // Construct your own path, by eg. 
            // appending custom base path to given path
            var myPath = ....;
            return register.Include(myPath)
    }

}
```

And now you can use `Style.CustomInclude(...)` instead of `Style.Include(...)` inside your shapes and get your custom stylesheet path.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is create a theme. The way to do it is described in [this page of the orchard documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme).